# HOW: Apache Camel, Regex match files

Tags: regex, apache, apache-camel

im experimenting in getting camel to do some file operations and pass them through the activeMQ broker, ive taken this project over from a guy who recently quit.

what ive got so far:

```
    <route id="SVLFTPCOPY">
  <from uri="sftp://*****:*******@********/srv/test/?fileName=*2280.xls&amp;noop=true&amp;idempotent=false"/>
    <to uri="file:/srv/data/test/destination/"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:svl.ftp.copy"/>
    </route>
```

it works to the point where it runs the route without throwing any errors, but still doesnt copy the file to the local file.

Any ideas?
.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yeah you need to use the include/exclude/filter option if you want to filter out files based on patterns. The fileName option is for a *single* file.

So in your case, remove fileName option and replace it with `include=.*2280.xsl`. Mind that the include is based on Java regular expressions, so we use *dot star* to indicate wildcard. More details here: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html. The ftp component inherits 99% of the options of the file component, so that is why I refer to the file wiki page.

Comment: It would be great to update the Camel WIKI page with a simple java regex 'include' and 'exclude' examples.

Comment: that's great. this answer saved my time: regex expression in the include should have dot before the star so it looks like: &include=.*2280.xsl. Otherwise it will not work

Comment: it should be .*2280\.xsl or .*2280[.]xsl

Comment: Use single BACKWARD slash("\") before the extension .xsl for java regex

Answer (score 7):

Use the `include` option that uses Java regular expression:

```
include=.*2280\\.xsl
```

Please, mind the `\\` before the dot `.`

Alternatively, use `antInclude`:

```
antInclude=*2280.xsl
```

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of filtering I recommend to use the [GenericFileFilter](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html#File2-Filterusingorg.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter)

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation of name matching, the following code is used:

```
if (ObjectHelper.isNotEmpty(endpoint.getInclude())) {
    if (!name.matches(endpoint.getInclude())) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So you can test which regular expression you should use. In you case, I think `.*2280\\.xsl` is what you should use.