# Migrating from service-mix file poller to apache camel file poller

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am new to apache camel. I want to migrate from service mix file poller to camel file poller. I am trying to do it, but currently I have nothing to test as I have to code this and give someone for testing. So can someone help me and check whether I am going in right way?

**Service-mix File Poller code:**

```
    <sm:activationSpec componentName="abcFilePoller"
        destinationService="b:destinationA"
        service="b:abcFilePoller">
        <sm:component>
            <bean class="org.apache.servicemix.components.file.FilePoller">
                <property name="file" value="file://D:/input" />
                <property name="period" value="20000"/>
                <property name="archive" value="file://D:/archive" />
                <property name="filter" ref="abcFileFilter" />
                <property name="marshaler">
                    <bean class="org.apache.servicemix.components.util.BinaryFileMarshaler" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </sm:component>
    </sm:activationSpec>
    <sm:activationSpec componentName="destinationA"
        service="b:destinationA">
        <sm:component>
            <bean
                class="com.abc.file.ABCReceiverComponent">
            </bean>
        </sm:component>
    </sm:activationSpec>
        <bean id="abcFileFilter" class="org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter">
<constructor-arg value="A*.ID" />
```

**Apache Camel File Poller**

```
    <camel:route id="abcFilePoller">
        <camel:from
            uri="timer://time?period=20000"/>
        <camel:pollEnrich uri="file://D:/input"/>
        <camel:filter ref="abcFileFilter"></camel:filter>
        <camel:to uri="file://D:/archive" />
        <camel:to uri="" />
    </camel:route>

<bean id="abcFileFilter" class="org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="A*.ID" />                                                                                                                                                                                             
</bean>
```

I have not completed the camel coding. I have left with destination part. And I have no idea about the `marshaler` that is used in the `service-mix` part. How to implement that `BinaryFileMarshaler` using camel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this even easier in Apache Camel where you can configure the filtering in the file endpoint, so it just becomes

```
   <route>
     <from uri="file:D:/input?delay=20000&amp;include=A.*ID"/>
     <to uri="file:D:/archive"/>
  </route>
```

Just mind that the include option uses a regular expression, so if you are not familiar with that it can take a bit tries to get the expression to work as expected. But its standard java regular expressions.

See more at: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html

And for new users to Apache Camel then see: http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache

Comment: Thanks. I have just implemented that already by seeing you answer in that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516843/how-apache-camel-regex-match-files . Can you please help me in this 'BinaryFileMarshaler' if possible.