# Camel from smb - combining "delete=true" and filtering by filename

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I need to convert files from extension A to B matching only a specific filename, The file with the original extension should be deleted on processing. However, other files in the directory should not be deleted. I am using Apache Camel 2.17.2 (and unfortunately cannot upgrade to newer version).

I have tried to combine the `delete=true` flag along with file filters, but it deletes all files, even though the filter works.

`from("smb://myDirectory?delete=true&password=xxxxxx&username=zzzz").
.filter(PredicateBuilder.and(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).startsWith("Report"),                             PredicateBuilder.not(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).endsWith("zip"))))`

This solution first converts the original files to my desired format, does not convert the converted file again - as expected - but then it also deletes the converted file because of the `delete=true` flag which as I understand has precedence over the filter.

I have also tried putting all this in the route parameters:

`from("smb://myDirectory?delete=true&fileName=Report*.csv&password=xxxxxx&username=zzzz")`

But then the regex does not match - I cannot understand why - and besides I think the problem may be the same even if I could get the regex to work. The filename example is `Report_Financial_20190201.csv`.

The only thing I can think of now is a `.choice().when()` condition, which would check the filename and extension and either convert it or not and put it in the target folder... which potentially results in an endless loop and generally seems like an awful hack.

What's the suggested approach to the problem?
Note: I cannot use a temp folder or anything like this due to requirements restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed these flags can be combined. I just needed to use the `include` option instead of `filename`. This answer helped me:
[HOW: Apache Camel, Regex match files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516843/how-apache-camel-regex-match-files)
My endpoint now looks like this:

`from("smb://myDirectory?delete=true&include=Report.*\\.csv&password=xxxxxx&username=zzzz")`

Comment: I was about to recommend combining the options, after reading `See File for more options as all the options from File is inherited.` in the [SMB Component's documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jcifs.html)